# How to make PowerApps based barcode scanner and Camera Control application work inside MS Teams

Tags: microsoft-teams, powerapps-canvas

I have a canvas application that uses two media inputs:

1. BardCode Scanner
2. Camera Control

The canvas application works perfectly in PowerApps own application.

But when I publish the application inside Teams environment both the functionalities are not working. It shows the message below: and the learn more link takes me to its limitation page document https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/powerapps/maker/canvas-apps/control-limitations

**Is there any way around to get those functionality running in the Teams environment?**

[image]

---

Moreover, I have a separate **angular application** which uses MS API to  **[Integrate QR or barcode scanner capability](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/concepts/device-capabilities/qr-barcode-scanner-capability)**. The application works fine in MS Teams ios and android app.

So, **Is there a way I could calibrate my barcode scanner angular app with PowerApps?**

Answer (score 1):

In order for a tab to access devices ( such a the camera or barcode scanner) you need to add this to your [Teams manifest](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/concepts/device-capabilities/qr-barcode-scanner-capability).
I'm assuming you did already add these capabilities

All tabs of any 3rp party Teams App **always** use the web view to render the Tabs.

- the Tab you created using a Canvas App renders in the (mobile) web browser
- PowerApps Barcode component is currently not working in mobile browsers ( per your link)

it is possible to create custom components for canvas apps using the [PCF framework](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerapps/developer/component-framework/component-framework-for-canvas-apps)
however I'm not sure if this will allow you to solve this issue, but it's worth a try.
perhaps start first by adding an existing PCF component from [the pcf gallery](https://pcf.gallery/canvas-controls)
to validate the embedding chain:

- Teams App [ Power App [ PCF [ bar code reader]]]